# Generating Minecraft-like terrain using Perlin noise in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to create a terrain generation system similar to that of Minecraft (hills, mountains, grasslands, rivers), where the terrain exhibits sinusoidal patterns. I've been exploring Perlin noise as a means to achieve this effect, but I'm struggling to produce the desired outcome. Could someone enlighten me on how to implement Perlin noise to generate terrain that features these characteristic grassland-like sinuous hills and valleys?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import noise

# Parameters for terrain generation
width = 256
height = 256
depth = 256  # New parameter for the third dimension
scale = 0.05  # Adjust this for different terrain scales
octaves = 6
persistence = 0.5

# Initialize an empty 3D array to store terrain data
terrain = np.zeros((depth, height, width))

# Generate terrain using Perlin noise
for z in range(depth):
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            value = noise.pnoise3(x * scale, y * scale, z * scale, octaves=octaves, persistence=persistence)
            terrain[z][y][x] = value

# Normalize terrain data to the range [0, 1]
terrain = (terrain - np.min(terrain)) / (np.max(terrain) - np.min(terrain))

# Create a 3D visualization of the terrain
x_coords, y_coords, z_coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height), np.arange(depth))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title('3D Minecraft-like Terrain with Grassland Sinusoidal Patterns')
terrain_plot = ax.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, c=terrain, cmap='terrain', marker='.')
fig.colorbar(terrain_plot, label='Elevation')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Presented here is an illustrative representation of the current state of my code. As observed, the Perlin noise values have coalesced into a cubic structure, a manifestation that diverges from the unintended outcome.

[image]

But what I was expecting was a sin wave like formation. How can I fix this?

Comment: There's some information missing between "but I'm struggling to produce the desired outcome" and "Could someone guide me", can you talk a bit about what you expected it to do (concretely), what you're seeing it do instead, and what you already (re)searched and debugged?

Comment: Why do you see that as a problem?  That looks like fairly natural random terrain to me.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm sorry for confusing you, I used the wrong example. I also added and edited my content so its more clear.

Comment: I think your expectations are flawed.  It's not supposed to give you sine waves.  It gives you bumpy textures, which you have.  It has "coalesced into a cubic structure" exactly because you asked for values for a cube.  If you want terrain, then you want 2D coordinates, and the value you get **back** is the elevation -- the Z value.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it. I have updated the question if you want to know. Anyways, to create a fluorescent and natural terrain resembling Minecraft's perlin noise, I need to generate a 2D perlin noise grid and extract elevation values (Z axis), then generate another perlin noise for depth and width which is 3D, and finally combine them together. Is that what I need to do? Or I’m not understanding it?

Comment: 1) It's worth pointing out that people have actually reverse engineered how Minecraft world generation works. https://www.alanzucconi.com/2022/06/05/minecraft-world-generation/ is a fairly good resource. 2) By tweaking your code in the way that Tim Roberts suggests, I'm able to get [this output](https://i.imgur.com/Ol3CP5U.png). Is this along the lines you were thinking?

Comment: @NickODell I'm thankful for your time and effort. Indeed, my goal is to replicate the smoothness of Minecraft's world generation. I've been trying it to do on countless questions in stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76861159/perlin-noise-in-python-noise-values-compacted-need-help-forming-sinusoidal-pat), I am trying to replicate your example and make it somewhat smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to get the elevation at each point, a simple way to do that is to change this from a 3D to a 2D problem, and interpret the value at each point as the elevation.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.ndimage
import noise
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,20)

# Parameters for terrain generation
width = 256
height = 256
scale = 0.01  # Adjust this for different terrain scales
octaves = 6
persistence = 0.5

# Initialize an empty 3D array to store terrain data
terrain = np.zeros((height, width))

# Generate terrain using Perlin noise
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        value = noise.pnoise2(x * scale, y * scale, octaves=octaves, persistence=persistence)
        terrain[y][x] = value

# Create a 3D visualization of the terrain
x_coords, y_coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title('3D Minecraft-like Terrain with Grassland Sinusoidal Patterns')
terrain_plot = ax.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, terrain, c=terrain, cmap='terrain', marker='.')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Plot output:

[image: terrain]

> I am trying to replicate your example and make it somewhat smooth.

If you're looking for something smooth, I would suggest using [a Gaussian filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html) to smooth the noise.

If you insert this code after your for loop:

```
filter_size = 3  # number of pixels per standard deviation for gaussian filter
terrain = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(terrain, filter_size)
```

The result is smoother. This is what it looks like at a filter size of 3:

[image: smoothed terrain]

Higher values of `filter_size` will make it smoother, smaller values with make it jaggier.